# sequential search backward

Tags: java, search, sequential

I am learning sequential search and have sequential search codes but I want to find numbers whose search process is from right (end of data) to left (beginning of data).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int []a={5,6,9,2,8,1,7};
        int key=8;
        boolean f=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if(key == a[i]){
                System.out.println("data found on index "+i);
                f=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (f=false){
            System.out.println("data not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you better explain this? What do you mean **find numbers**? Do you mean how many? Or do you mean the indexes found?

Comment: the indexes found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search from back to front, I think you can just edit for loop option.
`for (int i = a.length - 1 ; i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all indices that match the key then you can create a method that returns a Set of Integer values that represent each index found. You can also still use a simple for-loop from array.length - 1 to 0 for looping from right to left.

```java
    static Set<Integer> matchingIndices(int[] array, int key) {
        Set<Integer> indices = new HashSet<>();

        for (int index = array.length - 1; index > -1; index--) {
            int valueAtIndex = array[index];

            if (valueAtIndex == key) {
                indices.add(index);
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }
```

Example

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a= {5,6,9,2,8,1,7};

        int key = 8;

        Set<Integer> indices = matchingIndices(a, key);

        if (indices.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No index found for key.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Key found at following indices: " + indices);
        }
    }
```

If you want to find the first index from right to left with the same key just return an int and fail fast.

```java
    static int firstIndex(int[] array, int key) {
        for (int index = array.length - 1; index > -1; index--) {
            int valueAtIndex = array[index];

            if (valueAtIndex == key) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("No index found with the same key.");
    }
```

Example

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a= {5,6,9,2,8,1,7};

        int key = 8;

        try {
            int index = firstIndex(a, key);

            System.out.println(String.format("Found key at index %s", index));
        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            System.out.println("No index found.");
        }
    }
```